# Pandas rewriting function without calling apply

Tags: pandas

I need to create a derived field in a pandas dataframe based on the value in another field of the same dataframe. Like so:

```
def newfield(row):
 If row.col1 == ‘x’
  return ‘value is x’
Elif row.col1 == ‘y’
Return ‘value is y’
```

Then i call it:

```
df.newfield = df.apply(lambda row:newfield(row),axis=1)
```

Is there a way to do it without’apply’? Also would like to make it less verbose. Np.where only allows 2 conditions, but i have more than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `np.select`:

```
df['newfield'] = np.select([df['col1'] == 'x', df['col1'=='y'],
                           ['value is x', 'value is y'], 
                           np.nan)
```